# Time complexity of a string method in Java

Tags: java, string

What is the time complexity of the following Java *substring method*?

```
str.substring(start idx, ending idx);
```

I'm not sure what its time complexity is. Is it possible for us to calculate the time period taken by a program? I know time complexity is a different thing, but I want to know what time is actually taken by my program.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

A Java `String` is internally represented as a simple `char[]` character array.  The `String#substring()` method ultimately calls the constructor to return a *new* string, as Java strings are immutable.  Here is the [source code](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/String-source.html) for that constructor:

```java
public String(byte[] ascii, int hibyte, int offset, int count)
{
    if (offset < 0)
      throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset: " + offset);
    if (count < 0)
      throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("count: " + count);
    // equivalent to: offset + count < 0 || offset + count > ascii.length
    if (ascii.length - offset < count)
      throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset + count: "
                          + (offset + count));
    value = new char[count];
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = count;
    hibyte <<= 8;
    offset += count;
    while (--count >= 0)
      value[count] = (char) (hibyte | (ascii[--offset] & 0xff));
}
```

As you can see, the cost of taking a substring includes allocating a new `char[]` array, and then walking down the array of the source string, one character at a time, to populate the new array.  This is a linear operation and so should be bounded by `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of characters in the source string.  The required space boundary to hold the new substring is also `O(N)`.

Comment: The source you linked to is incredibly outdated, I don't think current OpenJDK even uses a char[] anymore, but the rest of this is correct.